# Asymptotic Symbol

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, asymptotics

I am reading a paper and trying to understand what the following statement means

$R(\hat{G}_{\text{chime}})-R_{\text{opt}}(\hat{G}_{\theta})\asymp\frac{\text{log}p}{n}$

I understand the left hand what I am trying to understand is $\asymp\frac{\text{log}p}{n}$

The paper is trying to find asymptotic bounds for misclassification errors of a new proposed clustering method.

Comment: That symbol might have different meaning depending on the context; so providing that context is important.

Comment: That's one of those symbols that gets defined different ways by different authors. The way I have mostly seen it used as "is logarithmically equivalent" which means  that the ratio of the log of one side to the log of the other side converges to $1$. Thus it is a very weak kind of asymptotic equivalence, much weaker than the difference going to zero or the ratio going to $1$. But out of context I can't see if that's a reasonable thing for this statement.

Comment: In partcular, how do $\hat{A}_{chime}$ and $\hat{A}_\theta$ depend on p and n?

Comment: $n$ is the sample size and $p$ is the dimension of the random vector  it is a clustering rule for $$p>>n$$ high dimension data

Answer (score 0):

My guess it would either mean that the ratio tends to one or that the ratio has a lower and upper bound
similar to $\Theta$.